# Reinventing .sort in ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, sorting

I'm challenged to create my own sorting method in Ruby. Here's what I've currently got:

```
sort_me = []
current_word = 'a'
sorted = []
puts "Enter a series of words or characters to be sorted! One word at a time, press enter when complete."

while current_word != ''
    current_word = gets.chomp
    sort_me.push current_word
end

puts ''
puts "You have chosen the values:"
puts sort_me

sort_me.each do |word|
    sort_me.each do |word2|
        if word > word2
            sorted.push word
        else
        end
    end
end

puts "They have been sorted thusly:"
puts sorted
```

What's going wrong with the nested .each section? In my mind it seems like it should compare each value in 'sort_me' to each other value with the > operand, then add them to 'sorted' starting with the highest value word on down. Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to do the Selection Sort: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each word will be pushed to the result array as many times as there are "smaller" words in the array. That's because the inner loop runs through all words and adds the word from the outer loop (`word`) as many times as `word > word2` holds true.

Comment: That totally makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

Your approach doesn't make much sense, for each word you'll push it to your result as many times as there exist lesser words in the whole collection.

Is the point of your exercise to develop a sort algorithm or to express it ruby?  If the later, try starting with [some well known algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm) and work out the details of implementing it in ruby.  If the former, you need to think clearly about your algorithm construction approach.  What strategy do you take to reduce the problem to a simpler form?  What are your invariants?  How do you assure that he algorithm makes progress to the goal? How do you demonstrate correctness?  Developing your own sort might be usefully informed by surveying the work that's gone before.  Expect whatever you come up with to be inferior to existing well known algorithms and implementations.

Comment: I've never thought about how to construct an algorithm before, let alone taken such precise steps to keep my strategy so well-defined. I just didn't understand what my code was doing, I wanted to understand -why- it was wrong, and work out how to fix it in my own head. Thanks for the tips, I'm sure future me will find them very helpful!